# Pause one action in SKSpriteNode while running another

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

Is there a way to pause certain action in an SKSpriteNode while running other actions on the same sprite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [run action with key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:withKey:), like this:

**Objective-C**

```
[yourNode runAction:yourAction withKey:@"aKey"];
```

Then you can access that particular action like this:

```
SKAction *action = [yourNode actionForKey:@"aKey"];

if(action){
   action.speed = 0; //pause action
}
```

**Swift**

To run an action with key:

```
yourNode.runAction(yourAction , withKey: "aKey")
```

To pause the action:

```
if let action = ball.actionForKey("aKey"){

    action.speed = 0

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this fixed the problem.